# How to make an adaptive display of csv data using the csv's header in check boxes and select option as sum, avg and mode USING php?

Tags: php, loops, csv, select, checkbox

As you can view in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUjPl.jpg), I am using a form which has check-boxes and a select option. Upon import of my CSV files using PHP, it displays the data correctly with the column headers. It also displays the CHECKED-boxes with its selected option only.

my csv file:

```
year, Exports of goods(F.O.B), Domestic exports, Re-exports.

1, 5, 10,20

1, 5, 10, 20

1, 5, 10, 20

1, 5, 10, 20
```

Thank you.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="sortable" >
   <?php #read CSV file

   if (($handle = fopen("sample1.csv", "r")) !== false) {
       $mycsv = array();
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
           $mycsv[] = $data;
       }
       fclose($handle);

       #Find the length of the transposed row
       $row_length = count($mycsv);
       echo "<form method='post' action=''><table><tr>";
       echo "<th><input type='checkbox' onClick='toggle(this)' /> Select/Deselect All<br/>
              </th>";
       echo "<th>Column</th>";
       echo "<th>Filter</th>";
       echo "</tr>";

       #Loop through each row (or each line in the csv) and output all the columns for that row
       foreach ($mycsv[0] as $col_num => $col) {
           echo "<tr>";
           for ($x = 0; $x < 1; $x++) {
               echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='lang[]'  value='" . $mycsv[$x][$col_num] . "' ></td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>" . $mycsv[$x][$col_num] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>
                    <select name='method[]' >
                     <option value=''>Choose</option>
                      <option  value='sum'>Sum</option>
                      <option  value='mean'>Mean</option>              
                      <option  value='average'>Average</option>
                      <option  value='highest'>Highest Value</option>
                      <option  value='lowest'>Lowest Value</option>
                    </select>
                      </td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }
       }
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' ></td>";
       echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='own_column' placeholder='Type your new column here'><br></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' name='own_column' placeholder='Own formula'><br></td>";
       echo "</tr>";

       //echo "<tr>";
       //echo "<td colspan='3' align='center'><input type='submit' name='Order'/></td>";
       //echo "</tr>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td colspan='3'><div class='wrapper'><br/><br/><input type='button' class='button' value='Input Button'>
                  </div></td>";
       echo "</tr>
                  <tr><td><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'</td></tr><table></form>";

       $post_data = $_POST["lang"];
       //$SelectedOption = $_POST['demo'];
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($post_data); $i++) {
           //echo "Selected : " . $post_data[$i]."</br>" ;
       }

       $row_length = count($mycsv);
       $col_length = count($post_data);
       $flag = true;
       $sum = array();

       foreach ($mycsv[0] as $key => $value) {
           foreach ($post_data as $search_term) {
               if (strcasecmp(trim($value), trim($search_term)) == 0) {
                   for ($row = 0; $row < $row_length; $row++) {
                       array_push($sum, $mycsv[$row][$key]);

                       if ($row == 0) {
                           echo "<tr>";
                           echo "<th colspan=100%>" . $mycsv[0][$key] . "</th>";
                           echo "</tr>";
                       } elseif ($row == 1) {
                           //echo "<td>" . $mycsv[$row][$key] . "</td>";
                           //echo "array sum =".array_sum($sum)."";
                       }

                       //echo " array sum =".array_sum($sum)."] ";
                   }

                   $method = $_POST["method"];

                   $method = $method[$key];
                   echo "<tr><td>";
                   if ($method == 'sum') {
                       echo "Sum of " . $value;
                   } elseif ($method == 'mean') {
                       echo "mean of " . $value;
                   } elseif ($method == 'average') {
                       echo "average of " . $value;
                   } elseif ($method == 'highest') {
                       echo "highest value of " . $value;
                   } elseif ($method == 'lowest') {
                       echo "lowest value of " . $value;
                   } else {
                       echo " Choose a method ";
                       echo "</td></tr>";
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   } ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stackoverflow exists to help you solve problems, not to write code for you. please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: hello, sorry, I thought i did post for where i have reached, I have updated it. Please check.